# VBA How to force a function to Return when a Form Button is pressed

Tags: vba, excel

I thought this would be simple, but it is proving quite difficult. Any advice or ideas would be appretiated.

I have a form in Excel that if a certain button is pressed I need the user to enter a password before the code for that button is run.

I could just use a inputbox, but that will allow anyone else to see the password when it is typed in. So I want to use a second form with a textbox and set it's PasswordChar parameter to *

Here is the problem. I want to use code like this

```
if checkPassword("Please enter your password") = False then exit sub
```

`checkPassword` is a function that takes a string as a parameter. This function opens a form and puts the message in to a lable. The user should enter the password and click OK.

the sub `btnOK_Click()` should check the password is correct and then force the function that opened the form to return True if the password was OK or False is the password was incorrect.

I just cant work out how to force the function to return. I have tried setting a global variable to either True or False when the user click OK and then unloading the form. This makes the Function return, but it also resets all the global variables set by the form.

Here is my function that calls the form

```
Function checkPassword(message As String) As Boolean

  frmPassword.Show
  frmPassword.passwordMsg.Caption = message

  'passwordStatus is a global variable
  If passwordStatus = True Then checkPassword = True Else  checkPassword = False

End Function
```

Here is the sub linked to the forms OK button:

```
Private Sub passwordok_Click()

  If Me.passwordtext.Text = "password" Then
      passwordStatus = True
  Else
      passwordStatus = False
  End If
  Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning a value from a dialog is a common task & pretty simple to do.

The simplest pattern is to put the function in the dialog form itself and have that function show its host form modally.

```
Private passwordStatus As Boolean

Function checkPassword(message As String) As Boolean
  '//setup the form
  Me.passwordMsg.Caption = message

  '//show the form modally, this will not return until the form is unloaded 
  '//i.e. when the button is clicked; so values in private variable are still valid
  Me.Show vbModal

  '//form is unloaded (via unload me or a close) return the value;
  checkPassword = passwordStatus
End Function

Private Sub passwordok_Click()
  passwordStatus = Me.passwordtext.Text = "password"
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Used as

```
passworkOk = frmPassword.checkPassword("enter your blabla")
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for this solution. I tried the solution from Siddharth and it worked fine (Many thanks to Siddharth again), but your solution is nearer to what I originally wanted to do. I have tried it and it works great, much simplier and loads smaller. Thanks

Comment: I used this, it works awsome, except that I had to put the `passwordStatus = Me.passwordtext.Text = "password"` after the `unload me` as the unload resets that variable, will this cause problems?

Answer (score 5):

> > > I could just use a inputbox, but that will allow anyone else to see the password when it is typed in. So I want to use a second form with a textbox and set it's PasswordChar parameter to *

Here is something from my database.

**DISCLAIMER**: I DIDN'T WRITE THIS AND I DON'T REMEMBER WHO WROTE THIS

**USAGE**:

```
Private Sub passwordok_Click()
    Dim Prompt, password As String
    Prompt = "Please enter your password."
    password = InputBoxDK(Prompt)

    MsgBox password '<~~ Do whatever you want to do with this
End Sub
```

**IN A MODULE**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandle Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetModuleHandleA" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
(ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendDlgItemMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendDlgItemMessageA" _
(ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'Constants to be used in our API functions
Private Const EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR = &HCC
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
Private Const HC_ACTION = 0

Private hHook As Long

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Dim RetVal
    Dim strClassName As String, lngBuffer As Long

    If lngCode < HC_ACTION Then
        NewProc = CallNextHookEx(hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
        Exit Function
    End If

    strClassName = String$(256, " ")
    lngBuffer = 255

    'A window has been activated
    If lngCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        RetVal = GetClassName(wParam, strClassName, lngBuffer)
        'Class name of the Inputbox
        If Left$(strClassName, RetVal) = "#32770" Then
            'This changes the edit control so that it display the password character *.
            'You can change the Asc("*") as you please.
            SendDlgItemMessage wParam, &H1324, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, Asc("*"), &H0
        End If
    End If

    'This line will ensure that any other hooks that may be in place are
    'called correctly.
    CallNextHookEx hHook, lngCode, wParam, lParam

End Function

Public Function InputBoxDK(Prompt, Optional Title, Optional Default, Optional XPos, _
Optional YPos, Optional HelpFile, Optional Context) As String
    Dim lngModHwnd As Long, lngThreadID As Long
    lngThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId
    lngModHwnd = GetModuleHandle(vbNullString)
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf NewProc, lngModHwnd, lngThreadID)
    InputBoxDK = InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, XPos, YPos, HelpFile, Context)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
End Function
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. I really wish I could cite a link for the original author instead of pasting the code above. If I ever find it, I will come back and edit this post. :)